# SQLAlchemy + Pydantic: set id field in db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I want to define a model using SQLAlchemy and use it with Pydantic.

Model definition:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass, sessionmaker
import pydantic

class Base(
    MappedAsDataclass,
    DeclarativeBase,
    dataclass_callable=pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass,
):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

class Transcript(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Transcript"

    id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(
        "id",
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        server_default=sa.text("gen_random_uuid()"),
    )
    text: Mapped[str] = mapped_column("text", Text)
    display_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column("display_name", String)
```

I run into a problem when I want to create a Transcript object.

```
transcript = {text: "hello", display_name: "world"} // dummy data for pydantic object
db_transcript = models.Transcript(**transcript.dict())
```

Error: `TypeError: Transcript.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'`

I can't figure out how to not require the field "id" of the SQLAlchemy model in the init function. Instead the id should be set in the db when the object is created for the first time.

Ideally I want the "id" to be None per default in the init function so that it gets overridden when the object is stored in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined the id to be a UUID field, Pydantic will expect it to be always provided. It will be required unless you specify it is Optional or it is `uuid.UUID | None` type. To fix that error you must make the id type optional:

```py
class Transcript(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transcript'

    id: Mapped[Optional[uuid.UUID]] = mapped_column(
        "id",
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        server_default=sa.text("gen_random_uuid()"),
        init=False,
        default=None
    )
```